# Unexpected token - JavaScript expression in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an input field which should be readonly based on some state change. So I have written the JSX like below:

```
render: function() {
var reo = 'readonly';
return (<input id="output" type="Text" value="0" {reo}/>);
}
```

In the above code variable `reo` is hardcoded but in the real scenario it will be evaluated based on some condition like:

```
var reo = (isDisabled ? 'readonly' : '');
```

When I am running this it is giving **unexpected token** error. Whereas when I am writing JSX like this:

```
<input id="output" type="Text" value="0" readonly/>
```

it is working fine. **Please explain me why this error is occurring and how to correct it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the example is that you pass a string while react expects a prop with the name `readonly`.

The following should work:

```
render: function() {
  var reo = true;
  return (
    <input id="output" type="Text" value="0" readonly={reo} />
  );
}
```

Or using `isDisabled`:

```
render: function() {
      return (
        <input id="output" type="Text" value="0" readonly={isDisabled} />
      );
    }
```

Comment: You must specify why the code of OP is not working and why your code will work.

Comment: Not sure what must means... :)  I am volunteering here :) The problem in the example is that you pass a string while react expects a prop with the name readonly...

Comment: Yup, I know, that's what I am saying. Just post some details about it in answer. :)